# Passing both a text_field_tag user input and a parameter to a controller action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, view, erb

Im working with the aws-sdk and ruby and rails to try and create a tool for uploading folders anywhere in the 'flat' file structure of amazon web services (aws)

Right now I have a form and id like to use it to pass a value along with the  user input thats entered into the text_field_tag .My form is as follows:

#

```
<h2>Create a Folder</h2>
  <%= form_tag({:action => 'create_folder'}, multipart: true) do %> 
  Please enter the folder name you wish to create: 
 <%= text_field_tag 'foldername' %>
  <br/> 
  <%= submit_tag 'Enter' %> <br />
 <% end %>
```

#

So in my controller#action(i.e. create_folder) , I would access the user input using params[:foldername]

The form is part of an index view in the corresponding action (index) of which I am accessing instance variables and modifying them and trying to pass them to the create_folder action along with user inputted 'foldername'. Assuming the result of the mdofication is 'value' , ***how would I pass both 'value' and 'foldername' to my create_folder action on clicking submit***.       id really appreciate thoughts and views on this.

**The value is a string obtained by modifying an instance from the action in which the view of the form is contained.**

**so for example: if my index action has a @variable -- I modify it in my view as value = @variable + "testvalue" and then need to pass this value alongwith the text_field_tag user input to another action on clicking the Enter button(or even without clicking )**

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what is 'value'. Please, review your question and rewrites it, so that we can help you.

Comment: @Americo I just edited it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hidden_field_tag and submit your value there within the form.

In the controller you should check this value because of security reasons..